# React useEffect onClick Refetch Data - Change Params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

How do I add a click handler to refetch data from my API based on my input ON CLICK?

In my console I'm getting back data if I input "Jon Snow" for instance because the `onChange` set to `e.target.value` but not sure how to fetch this on button click.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lichterman-4ev6f?file=/src/game.jsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Game() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( name );
  }
  const handleClick = e => {
    // ??
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters?name=${name}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data[0].name); // the data I want back
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [name]);

  return (
    
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={handleClick}/>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you want to call the api while clicking on the button?

Comment: i would like to pass the input value as the "name" param in the url

Comment: Are you want to call the api onChanging name or on Submitting the value?

Comment: when i click the button ideally

Comment: Initial state with name "", do you want to call the api?

Answer (score 2):

When the Submit button is clicked it will trigger onSubmit event, no need for you to handle the onClick event separately.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Game() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( name );
    fetchData(name);
  }
  
  const fetchData = (name) => {
    fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters?name=${name}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data[0].name); // the data I want back
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(name);
  }, []);

  return (
    
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={handleClick}/>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, how would i print the returned API data to my page?

Comment: You can create a new state and update it in the then block

Answer (score 1):

Add another stateful variable. You need not only a value and setter for the *input value* but also a value and setter for the API results you want to be able to use elsewhere. Maybe something like

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
const [result, setResult] = useState('');
```

```
// inside fetch callback:
setResult(data[0]?.name ?? ''); // use optional chaining to not throw an error
// if there is no result
```

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={searchText}
  onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
  placeholder="Name"
/>
```

And then you can use the `result` where you need.

Live demo:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState('');
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState('');

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( name );
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters?name=${searchText}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setResult(data[0] ? data[0].name : '');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
        setError(error);
      });
  }, [searchText]);
  console.log(result);

  return (
    
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}/>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: where does the callback go?

Comment: The same place where you're using `data[0].name` currently. Just replace that line with the new `setResult(data[0]?.name ?? '');`

Comment: i think i’m lost. didn’t work for me. did what you said

Comment: It looks to work for me, see snippet. But the API you're using has problems, it rarely returns array items from user input. See https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters it looks like all the names are empty. Find a better API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct state variable [name] in handleClick function.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct that you should trigger the fetch in your `handleSubmit`.  I just wanted to chime in with some sample code for rendering results since you asked for help with that.

The API returns an array of characters.  We want to `map` through that result and show each character.  We also want to tell the user if there were no results (especially since this API seems to only work with an exact name and will return a result for "Arya Stark" but not for "Stark").  We don't want to show that "No Characters Found" message before they have submitted.

I am using a `setState` hook to store the array of `character` matches from the `API`.  I am initializing the state to `undefined` instead of `[]` so that we only show the no results message if it gets set to `[]`.

My code allows the user to submit multiple times.  We keep displaying the previous results until they submit a new search.  Once we have an array in our `characters` state, we display those results.

```
// an example component to render a result
const RenderCharacter = ({ name, aliases }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      {aliases.length && (
        <div>
          <h3>Aliases</h3>
          <ul>
            {aliases.map((a) => (
              <li key={a}>{a}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
export default function Game() {
  // current form input
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  // save characters returned from the API
  // start with undefined instead of empty array
  // so we know when to show "no characters found" message
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState();
  // store API errors
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters?name=${name}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setCharacters) // store data to state
      .then(() => setError(null)) // clear previous errors
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
        setError(error);
        setCharacters(undefined); // clear previous character matches
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Name"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      {characters !== undefined &&
        (characters.length === 0 ? (
          <div>No Characters Found</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {characters.map((character) => (
              <RenderCharacter key={character.name} {...character} />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      {error !== null && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/game-of-thrones-character-api-85z5q?file=/src/App.tsx) (with typescript annotations)